# PHP connect to serial Comm

Tags: php, class, serial-port

How might php can connect to serial Comm?

I try use a class [php_serial.class.php](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17926.html) but that does not work, when I run the web, error occurs

```
Warning: Specified serial port is not valid in D:\POS\AppServ\www\Eri\ulikan\phptoserial\gagal\php_serial.class.php on line 111

Warning: The device must be set before to be open in D:\POS\AppServ\www\Eri\ulikan\phptoserial\gagal\php_serial.class.php on line 137

Warning: Device must be opened in D:\POS\AppServ\www\Eri\ulikan\phptoserial\gagal\php_serial.class.php on line 541

Warning: Device must be opened to read it in D:\POS\AppServ\www\Eri\ulikan\phptoserial\gagal\php_serial.class.php on line 474

Warning: Unable to set the baud rate : the device is either not set or opened in D:\POS\AppServ\www\Eri\ulikan\phptoserial\gagal\php_serial.class.php on line 204
```

Comment: Where di you get that class from? It probably needs some kind of extension loaded.

Comment: From php_serial.class.php, What extensions do you know that? : (Please help me

Comment: Maybe you should contact [the author](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17926.html) at thenux at gmail dot com.

Comment: Firstly, please can you add the code you have written to try and use this to the question, and secondly are you running this on Windows?

Comment: @Mchl He seems to be using [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17926.html) and incredibly it doesn't need any extensions, it uses `fopen()` on file system paths - which I can see working on *nix with its `/dev/tty*` file system, but I had no idea you could do it on Windows - and looking through the code, the author seems to think that you can.

Comment: Show your code how you use that class.

Comment: *Warning: Specified serial port is not valid* - I assume you need to specify a valid serial port. Which ones do you have on your system? Please provide a list of those and please show your code where you configure the class.

Comment: sorry in advance if I am late to answer questions, because the code is too long, I will be included in the pastebin, for php_serial.class.php http://pastebin.com/pUidiC0x  and my script http://pastebin.com/pR7FLfCP